# Can I load my local Windows install into a Linux virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have Linux and Windows both installed on dual boot. How can I load my existing Windows installation into a VMWare Workstation while I'm booted into Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools that go by the name "physical to virtual" aka. p2v to convert a physical system to a virtual system. There are a number of tools that can do this. The one that VMware provides is available here:

- [vCenter Converter](https://www.vmware.com/products/converter/)

There are a number of tutorials, [such as this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdehhlYA4ZY) that demonstrate the entire task.

If you don't want to use VMware's product there are others as well. The Wikipedia article titled: [Physical to Virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical-to-Virtual) has more on the subject. This SpiceWorks thread titled: [Best software for P2V Conversion](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/371666-best-software-for-p2v-conversion), has a pretty extensive list in the comments about all the tools in this category.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got `VMWare Workstation`, but a quick Google suggests it cannot be done.  You can share the disk with a guest, but the guest has to be running already, which isn't the case in your scenario.

An alternative would be use a different virtualization system such as `KVM` or `VirtualBox` as these can access the physical drive directly.

Windows doesn't like it when you change the underlying hardware (eg motherboard) and there would be quite a bit of repair work needed if you do this using any virtualization package (inc VMWare) as to all intent and purposes the change from your physical computer to a virtual one is a change of motherboard and associated peripherals as far as Windows is concerned. You would then need to carry out more repair if you were to reboot and run the Windows installation directly as you'd be changing 'hardware' again from the VM back to the physical.

I've done a similar thing with running a Linux install both as a boot option and as a guest in another distro and that works fine as Linux is far more tolerant.

WARNING -You should never boot into an installation (whether it be Windows or Linux) and boot that same partition as a VM guest at the same time - it will cause unbelievable pain!